Sample size for a discrete-time survival model with a time-dependent covariate
How can I calculate the sample size for a prediction model (Cox regression) when the survival time is discrete (up to 6 points) and there is also a time dependent variable (with three categories) in the model? Is there a package formula in R to do this? If not, how can I do it by simulation? Any sharing source of coding in R would be highly appreciated.
